# Hover over an image above another one

Tags: html, css, image, hover, zooming

I'm trying to make a zoom on hover over an image, I have two images, the second one is correct as you can see but I have a problem with the first one and I don't understand where this is coming from.

```css
.examples {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.examples img {
aspect-ratio: 3/2;
object-fit: contain;
padding: 10px;
width: 20%;
margin: auto;
background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, .65);
border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .09);
backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
transition: transform .4s;
}

.examples>img:hover {
transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="examples">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/400x400" alt="Free unsplash image">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/400x400" alt="Free unsplash image">
</div>
```

It actually fixes itself if I take away the dark border but with the border it doesn't work and I would like to keep the border. Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what it is that isn't working - I am not clear from the pictures you have given. Perhaps if you could create a runnable snippet it would make it clearer - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: Yeah I'm gonna try, it's my firs time posting something and I don't know how to make a runnable snippet

Comment: Yeah I'm not understanding how the runnable snippet works, I added the page to GitHub so you can fully see it and possibly help me with the problem I'm facing, Thanks  https://github.com/KristianMellina/Image-Problem

Comment: Hi, sorry SO does want the code in your question because an outside site could disappear then your question is no use to future readers. Edit your question and use the <> icon to insert the snippet.

Comment: Ok I figured out how to do the snippet, now it works and you can see what the problem is. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: What do you actually want it to look like on hover? Is the background still to be semi transparent (ie so the other image shows through? Your basic problem seems to be the filter, which creates a new stacking context. Do you need to keep the filter?

Comment: Yes I just found out that the filter is the problem, I would like to keep the filter if possible since all the pages have this filter. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial solution in the hopes it may be sufficient in your use case, or at least help towards a fuller answer.

The problem arises because filter creates a new stacking context, so no amount of z-index setting is going to make a difference, the second img will always be on top.

This snippet removes the filter blur on all the children on hover of the parent, restoring it just for the img that is being hovered (hence you get a blurred version of the other img when an img is hovered.

```css
.examples {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.examples img {
  aspect-ratio: 3/2;
  object-fit: contain;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, .65);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .09);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  transition: transform .4s;
}

.examples:hover>img {
  backdrop-filter: none;
}

.examples>img:hover {
  transform: scale(2.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="examples">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/400x400" alt="Free unsplash image">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/400x400" alt="Free unsplash image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this completely solved my problem!